# ngResource not saving properties added since loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm connecting to a service and retrieving an item via angular resource:-

```
$rootScope.currentItem = Entity.get({ id: $stateParams.id }, function() {

});
```

This fetches me an entity with properties val1,val2,val3

now I bind a form to currentItem properties val1,val2,val3,***val4***

all these fields update the model in the root scope according to ng-inspector

however when I run `$rootScope.currentItem.$save` it only sends back val1, val2 and val3 (looking at the network tab in chrome dev tools).

How do I get it to re-evaluate the present fields? (the web service has many many optional fields, and won't include them unless there's data present)

For clarification Entity is defined simply as a standard ngResource:

```
.factory('Entity', function($resource) {
return $resource("http://localserver/app/api/entity/:id",
                     {id: '@id'
                     },
                     { //methods
                        update: {
                            method: 'PUT'
                        }
                     }
                    );
})
```

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: I will need an example. Like that is hard to say what's going wrong

Comment: @WayneEllery I've added the factory definition for Entity to the question.

Comment: You could use save instead of $save

Comment: try to bind with an object, like '$rootScope.myObj.currentItem', but not directly with the data itself.

Comment: @WayneEllery I'd like to try that. I understand it'd be Entity.save({id: 123}, $rootScope.currentItem) but what's the rest of the function spec look like? - I need to perform an action on completion too (I can only seem to find reference to $save in the angular docs)

Comment: Yeah the documentation isn't the greatest. You can use `Entity.save({id: 123}, $rootScope.currentItem)` What do you mean the rest of the function spec?

Comment: @WayneEllery normally there's a few optional params like a function to run on completion, eg: myws.$save(function(){
                                    //do something after save
                                    });

Comment: The first parameter is optional. If you are creating a new record pass in null. You do the same, `Entity.save({id: 123}, $rootScope.currentItem, function () { //do something}, function () {//error})`. This is in the docs. Scroll down to Returns. "non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])"

Comment: @WayneEllery, how would I run something after save() is complete (like the example in my previous comment does with $save)? do we pass in a function, receive a promise?

Comment: I updated my comment. You can also get a promise by using `Entity.save({id: 123}, $rootScope.currentItem).$promise`

Comment: Right, I tried using save and it does the same thing. I'm wondering if ngResource builds some code that is based on the fields at the time of creation (retrieval from the web service). Is there a way to convert the ngResource object back to a regular json object (ie strip out the angular enhancements so for example .$save would not exist). Perhaps then I can rebuild the object with new Entity(stripped_json)?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a plunkr. I wouldn't think that save would do the same thing.

Comment: Plunkr is blocked here :/ (I love corporate firewalls...)